# I want to wire in a single gang light switch for a lamp

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a lamp with a weird switch on it so I want to attach a light switch to it and place it on the wall. I do not want to use an inline switch as they are often fiddly too. I have been trying all combinations of wiring but can never find the right combo. So what goes to l1,l2 and com. Thanks.

Comment: First we have to agree on terminology. The lamp should be fed with a hot wire, a neutral, and a ground wire if it has metallic parts.  Possibly the hot would be L1, the neutral would be L2 and the ground would be common. But I have never seen a lamp labeled L1,L2, and com. What country are you in?

Comment: Hi, I'm in the uk.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no connection other than live/hot/line to the switch. Therefore, the neutral and earth are connected directly to the fitting. The incoming live connects to com, the outgoing L1 connects to the fitting. L2 indicates that this is a two way switch. Connecting anything else to the switch will cause a dead short. The fitting is switched on the live only.